# gamma-ray spectrum vs energy decay

Tags: geophysics, radioactivity

I am going through *An Introduction to Applied and Environmental Geophysics*, a book by *John Reynolds* (2011), to better understand radiometrics and gamma-ray spectrometry. The author provides some tables about decaying as well as a plot of airborne gamma-ray spectrometry data.

Table 15.2A shows the Uranium decay series, while Table 15.2C shows the Thorium decay series. The plot shows the survey result of an airborne gamma-ray spectrometry.

As one can see in the plot, the author relates

- the Potassium series with peak at 1,46 MeV with corresponding element <sup>40</sup>K
- the Uranium series (shown in Table 15.2A) with peak at 1,76 MeV with corresponding element <sup>214</sup>Bi
- the Thorium series (shown in Table 15.2C) with peak at 2,82 MeV with corresponding element <sup>208</sup>Tl

The problem is: for both Uranium and Thorium decay series shown, the decay values presented at the tables differ from the peaks at the plot. I would expect to see the Uranium series peak with a value of 3.272 MeV (<sup>214</sup>Bi decay value in Table 15.2A) instead of 1,76 MeV shown in the plot.

The same for Thorium series: if the corresponding decay energy of <sup>208</sup>Tl is 5.001 MeV accordingly to Table 15.2C, why does the plot show a corresponding value of 2.82 MeV?

[image: Uranium decay series]
[image: Thorium decay series]
[image: airborne gamma-ray spectrometry]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will first focus on the <sup>214</sup>Bi decay. The 3.272 MeV is the total amount available *for the β<sup>-</sup> decay*, i.e. the difference between the ground states of <sup>214</sup>Bi and <sup>214</sup>Po. If you have a beta decay into the ground state of of <sup>214</sup>Po, which happens in 19.9 % of cases (all data are from Firestone, R. B. et al., “Table of Isotopes”, 8th ed., 1998, p. 9211, in short “ToI”), there will be no gamma emission from <sup>214</sup>Po, the 3.272 MeV are distributed between the electron and the electron antineutrino. However, in 16.9 % of cases, the decay leads to an excited state of <sup>214</sup>Po with an energy of 1764.499 keV which can then deexcite among other possibilities by emission of a 1764.494 keV gamma photon (15.36 % of beta decays). The decay can produce a large number of gamma ray lines, but most happen with low probability. You can have a look at page 23 of this [<sup>214</sup>Bi table of radionuclides extract](http://www.nucleide.org/DDEP_WG/Nuclides/Bi-214_tables.pdf) to get an impression.

In summary, the 3.272 MeV get distributed in varying proportion to the electron and the electron antineutrino from the beta decay, zero or more gamma-ray photons, and some small amount to nuclear recoil, etc.

In the case of <sup>40</sup>K decaying via electron capture to <sup>40</sup>Ar (10.72 % of cases), the total decay energy (Q-value) is 1504.9 keV. Most of the time (10.67 %), this goes to an excited state (1460.859 keV), which in turn gives rise to the 1460.830 keV gamma-ray line. The rest of the energy goes to the electron neutrino.

Similarly, for <sup>208</sup>Tl, the 5000.9 keV is the Q-value of the β<sup>-</sup>-decay. Most of the time (48.7 %), the decay proceeds via an excited state (3197.743 keV) of <sup>208</sup>Pb, which deexcites via another excited state (2614.551 keV) where 99 % of decays also lead. This state the deexcites via the emission of a 2614.533 keV gamma ray photon. I believe the 2.82 MeV from Fig. 15.1 is a typo, since the reference in Reynolds’ book points to the article “[Airborne Gamma-Ray Spectrometry Surveys](http://www.geoexplo.com/airborne_survey_workshop_rad.html)”. There Fig. 4.4-1 is the same as Fig. 15.1 from the book, but in rather low resolution and with hard-to-read numbers. The text, however discusses the 2.62 MeV gamma ray line, which is very likely a rounded value of the 2614.533 keV from the “Table of Isotopes”.

The sum of the probabilities of different gamma ray lines from the same decay can be larger than 100 % if the deexcitation happens via a gamma-ray cascade, i.e. if the nucleus first transitions into an intermediate excited state and then again to the ground state or further intermediate states. This means that a single beta decay results in multiple gamma-ray emissions. This is illustrated in the Wikipedia article on [Gamma rays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_ray#Decay_schemes) using the example of the <sup>60</sup>Co decay which results in two photons emitted in > 99.9 % of cases.

Comment: First of all, thank you @Karsten Kretschemer. 

Secondly, your explanation makes a lot of sense for _Bi_. Why wouldn't it for _Tl_? I just can imagine that or either your explanation about _Bi_ is a great coincidence (which I personally don't believe) or may there be some mistyped data? Can't see why.

Third, why does the Gamma-ray probabilities (firstmost column to the right of energy column) from _Bi_ sum up 100% (or seems so), while for  _Tl_ it surpasses 100%?

Comment: @LeonardoMiquelutti I have edited to hopefully address your comment